# Serving Pyramid application using twistd

Tags: python, twisted, pyramid

I have a Pyramid app that also has some Twisted code in it, and so I would like to serve the app using twistd to kill two birds with one stone.

Here is my .tac file:

```
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.application import internet, service
import os

from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging

config='/path/to/app/production.ini'
config = os.path.abspath(config)
port = 8888

application = get_app(config, 'main')

# Twisted WSGI server setup...
resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), application)
factory = Site(resource)

service = internet.TCPServer(port, factory)

service.setServiceParent(application)
```

To run this I used:

```
twistd -y myApp.tac
```

I am getting errors telling me that the get_app() method does not return an object that can be used in this way. E.g.:

```
"Failed to load application: 'PrefixMiddleware' object has no attribute 'addService'"
```

What is the best way to run a Pyramid app using twistd?

Comment: Looks like your self-answer is correct, but in the future, please attach full tracebacks, along with the full shell command you typed to get the error.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the WSGI support in Twisted Web's `twistd` plugin to shorten this and make it more easily configurable.  Create a module like this:

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app

config = '/path/to/app/production.ini'
myApp = get_app(config, 'main')
```

Then run `twistd` like this:

```
$ twistd web --port tcp:8888 --wsgi foo.myApp
```

Where `foo` is the name of the module you create.

Comment: Note: need `--port tcp:8888` in recent versions of twistd.

Answer (score 2):

I found a working solution. Here is the working .tac file:

```
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.application import internet, service
import os

from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging

config='/path/to/app/production.ini'
config = os.path.abspath(config)
port = 8888

# Get the WSGI application
myApp = get_app(config, 'main')

# Twisted WSGI server setup
resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), myApp)
factory = Site(resource)

# Twisted Application setup
application = service.Application('mywebapp')
internet.TCPServer(port, factory).setServiceParent(application)
```

get_app() gets the Pyramid WSGI application, while internet.TCPServer needs a Twisted  Application object, so these should not be confused.

This code will start the app on TCP port 8888.

If someone has a better/clearer way to implement this, please add your answer.

Comment: did you stick with this solution? is it stable?

Comment: @mix As far as I know it is still running. I am not sure, since I dont own the code/service anymore, and I haven't tried it in production since. What are your experiences?

Comment: none yet ;) I just have some twisted stuff and a pyramid application and think of running both as one service. Thanks for your feedback